# Why would people want a benevolent AI-controlled society?

Tags: society, politics, artificial-intelligence, gods, future

Inspired by the Orion’s Arm worldbuilding project, I am imagining a science-fiction scenario where humans are ruled over by entities known as GODS, or Geocomputing Directories. These are computer systems built into the very fabric of a planet; processors built by nanotech 10km beneath the surface, powered by the raw heat of the mantle, which control the planet using a field of utility fog in the atmosphere. They can manipulate the weather, not to the point of blasting folks with lightning bolts, but they can “sculpt” clouds to create localised rainfall or droughts. They can interface with the internet and monitor communications, and use their individual foglets (which basically function as individual photoreceptors) to observe the goings on of everyone and everything.

Despite all this power, the GODs are relatively benevolent, having been programmed to function as the perfect rulers; firm but fair, and not even considering their own personal gain when making any decision. Although effectively removing any kind of privacy to those not willing to live under a rock, both figuratively and literally, the GODs offer a better system of government than any human ruler can.

Nevertheless, given that the Media has basically biased mankind against AI rule, and this still applies in the project, under what conditions would people in the future *voluntarily* create a GOD to rule them in the first place?

Comment: Your headline asks why people would want an AI-governed society, but in your question you lay out the precise advantages to such a society and conclude that it is superior in almost every way to a human-governed one. That seems like a pretty good reason to want it, to me. What is your actual question?

Comment: People seldom want what is good for them; rule by a God may be better, but consider telling everyone on Earth that they are to be ruled by a god-like computer intelligence hidden underground that can watch their every movement. Consider their reaction, preferably from a safe distance, like in low-Earth orbit.

Comment: Part of human development is to rebel against authority. That has allowed us to move out of the family and colonize the whole world. When a GOD understands that, it would allow humans to do their own thing and not try to rule the world. Only part of humanity wants to live under a GOD's rule. This would be part of the tension in any such story.

Comment: Asking about plot, circumstances, and/or character choices is storybuilding and off-topic.

Comment: Back reading: the benevolent dictator or "philosopher king".  https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictatorship

Comment: Seems like the closers [confused what is plot vs what is sociology](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8312/80336). I will vote to reopen it if you gave some constraints, social context and some goals to reach, as your question is looking a bit too much like a brainstorm. What I'm looking from you for instance : "I don't want evident mind control as answers", "my society is based on individuality and freewill", or "I would like the most insidious way of doing this". N.B. : That's just 3 examples, not necessarily what you have/want.

Comment: Incidentally, questions about culture (which this is), is explicitly defined within the rules of Worldbuilding as an acceptable question. "World building includes geography, culture and creatures for the world".

Comment: I don't believe there could be a single solid reason for this. I can think of a few ways to work a story around to this, but that's the problem. It's entirely opinion based and, worse, I feel like you're asking for your story's back-story. Good for a round-table discussion among friends, not so good for a best answer selection.

Comment: It also seems to be asking multiple questions, because an answer has to deal with the bias against AI before suggesting under what conditions an AI ruler would be created. And both are at least partially story-based.

Answer (score 3):

Just this morning I was reading in the newspaper that, according to a research from a Spanish university, in many country more than half of the citizens would be in favor of replacing the parliament with an AI.

While I am pretty sure that a good part of those in favor has seen the Matrix, Terminator, 2001 a Space Odissey and all the other movies which do not give a good depiction of AI, I can also imagine that, in a context where the political class is perceived as incapable and easily corruptible, worried more about its own interests than of the collective good, it's understandable that this distrust in the human turns into trust in the machine.

And don't forget that somehow we tend to trust computers more than humans: how many people ride their car in impossible roads just because "the navigator said so"? I remember reading of a study where the test subjects continued following the directions of a robot, even when it was evident that it wasn't able to guide them to the exit of the building which they were supposed to leave with its help.

In your case it can be the same, a combination of distrust in the humans and excessive trust in the machine.

Answer (score 2):

## Places without AIs tend to nuke or kill themselves

Manufacturing is advanced enough that it's pretty easy to make nuclear weapons or biological weapons or grey nanotech swarms. Human ruled settlements have repeatedly made the emotional decision that the only way to handle their enemies is to nuke them, or use a biological plague, or to use swarms of nanites to eat them. Their enemies have retaliated, and it destroys the colony.

Only the cold unemotional mind of AIs is enough to stop this chain of events.

Comment: Gods are not unemotional; their thoughts may be incomprehensible to humans, but their benevolence towards humans is even more so. However, I like the idea of a kind of geopolitical “natural selection” weeding out any countries that reject AI rule.

Comment: Benevolence isn't an emotion, and you can obviously make your AIs however you want in terms of emotion.

Answer (score 2):

### AIs don't take bribes.

The AIs don't need anything; they literally live to serve. As such, they can't be bribed. On second thought, let me rephrase that: they *can* be bribed, but only if they decide that it will advance society's interests.

### The General Will of the People

As Rousseau (grudgingly) pointed out, there's a difference between people's Common Will (what they *think* they want, which you can determine with elections and polls) and their General Will (what they subconsciously *actually* want, which can only be determined by having an intimate knowledge of every single person's needs). This division causes utopian societies to fall into two traps, destroying them.

First, an individual's Common Will generally outweighs the people's General Will in a leader's mind. As a result, you end up with "pork barrel" projects, wherein the leaders decide to enrich themselves or their friends at the expense of the people as a whole. This can either occur consciously ("The General Will of the people is that I have a new summer dacha") or unconsciously. An example of the latter would be giving a job to a friend instead of some random bloke because your acquaintance with him biases you. An AI is immune to this; it has no private wants or desires.

Second, human leaders aren't omniscient. Even if they have all the raw data available to them, they can't *know* everything about their subjects. As a result, they're forced to work off of the Common Will, which is usually determined by whoever shouts the loudest. An AI, on the other hand, has the ability to process all the raw data, allowing it to come to actually know the General Will<sup>†</sup>.

Third, they lack a good basis for morality and ethics. Most Utopian schemes reject morality based on absolutes (be they natural law or God's nature) in favor of utilitarianism ("the ends justify the means"). As Francis Schaeffer argued, this is an inevitable side effect of their atheistic rationalism. The problem with utilitarianism is that it doesn't say that anything is wrong. It justifies everything, so long as it's for a good cause. Thus, corrupt leaders are able to excuse horrible things like pogroms and "disappearing" political prisoners by saying that they are promoting the Greater Good<sup>TM</sup>. Because the Greater Good is so nebulous, it's almost impossible to prove that such things aren't bringing it about. Because your AIs are always (at least theoretically) working for the Greater Good, you can trust that they are *actually* doing the "right" thing.

**TL;DR: Since it knows the General Will, an AI can be trusted to rule justly.**

### People hate their betters.

As Marx observed, a lot of society's strife (I won't go so far as to say all like he did) is due to class conflicts. People tend to hate (or at least dislike) their superiors<sup>*</sup>. If you replace the government with an AI, it puts all those stuck up ****ing bureaucratic pigs out of a job.

---

<sup>† More or less. The best Rousseau ever managed was "you'll know it when you see it" (intuition), aided by abolishing private property (which he believed to be the source of all division and evil in the world).</sup>

<sup>* This is often for good reason. Avaricious people tend to screw over whoever they can in order to advance their own fortunes. This causes them to rise to the top while lowering others. Another potential advantage of an AI government is that it could be trusted to curb the ambitions of these sorts of people without becoming one of them, as usually happens in socialist systems.</sup>

Comment: A generally good answer, except that it laughably misconstrues the reasons why people of lower class hate their "betters." It's not merely unmotivated mutual dislike. "Behind every great fortune is a great crime" is true often as not: the upper class is where you find everybody who succeeded by preying upon their fellows and escaping punishment (nobody cheats to _lower_ their station). It is also the place where the undeserving, spoiled scions accumulate from both good and evil wealthy forebears: the bloated sons of the vicious rich.

Comment: I did not say that it's unmotivated; quite the opposite. However, I'll edit my answer to make what I'm saying more clear.

Answer (score 1):

**It's really a question of culture.**

Why would people want to live under an authoritarian dictatorship like North Korea? Well, it's what they've always known. Plus there's always propaganda and punishment. (The leader is the best! All other nations are awful places where the people suffer! The leader loves you! You love the leader! Or else!)

So if the situation is that the AI appears *on Earth, tomorrow*, then yeah, I would expect staunch resistance. If it's the year 2300 and the AI has slowly crept up in ability and control over 200-300 years then people may simply accept it as the natural order of things, as we pretty well do with all things today.

Of course, humans will probably never be some monolithic group. There will always be the greedy, the corrupt, the luddites, those seeking to gain power for themselves or overthrow the AI, because reasons, but if the GODS have eliminated major causes of social uprising -- such as droughts, plagues, famine, economic collapse, etc -- then it may simply be that people are *content* with the "benevolent AI controlled society" and any rebels or mafias have a hard time getting enough traction to do more than localized crime. A content society is not one that's going to take up arms and risk their lives in an uprising.